# How to get the Check the Diagnostic settings for a Database in Azure using Powershell

Tags: sql, azure, powershell, azure-sql-database

I am trying to check for which Database in Azure Diagnostic settings is not enabled. Is there any way through PowerShell I can do this?

Also how to enable Diagnostic settings for multiple databases using Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/metrics-diagnostic-telemetry-logging-streaming-export-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#configure-the-streaming-export-of-diagnostic-telemetry

Powershell
Set-AzDiagnosticSetting
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/set-azdiagnosticsetting?view=azps-4.4.0

Personally a fan of CLI so I will include that as well
azure insights diagnostic 

Scripts to enable diagnostics logging are supported for Azure CLI v1.0. Azure CLI v2.0 is unsupported at this time.